# Problem with EventEmitter and CustomEvent

Tags: node.js, angular, angular8, angular-event-emitter

**Angular 8.3.14 project.**

We made an EventEmitter for sharing a string with the parent component.

**Child Component**

```
@Output() pepe = new EventEmitter<any>();

ngOnInit() {
   this.pepe.emit('pepe');
}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<child-selector (pepe)="sample($event)"></child-selector>
```

**Parent component TS**

```
sample(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

The problem is we are receiving a CustomEvent object in the sample function. That object has a property with the current value, but why are we receiving a CustomEvent instead of the string? This is something we have never seen.

**CustomEvent object received in the sample function**

```
CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: "Test string", type: "addonsChange", target: wc-ocs-addons-mosaic, currentTarget: wc-ocs-addons-mosaic, …}
isTrusted: false
detail: "Test string"
type: "addonsChange"
target: wc-ocs-addons-mosaic
currentTarget: null
eventPhase: 0
bubbles: false
cancelable: false
defaultPrevented: false
composed: false
timeStamp: 8043.915000045672
srcElement: wc-ocs-addons-mosaic
returnValue: true
cancelBubble: false
path: (8) [wc-ocs-addons-mosaic, div.amena-cms, ocs-theme, app-demo, body, html, document, Window]
__proto__: CustomEvent
```

[CustomEvent IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxE9H.png)

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the emit function outside of ngOnInit and check the result.